# Как сделать стрелки без доп элементов?

Tags: html, css

или нельзя? только свг? или можно? как то
одну еще как -то можно. Но две..
[image]

Comment: [шрифтами](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/icons/angle-double-up?style=solid), например

Comment: Или спецсимволы: https://unicode-table.com/ru/sets/brackets/

Comment: Хотя на svg легче всего

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте

```css
.gray{background:#777;height:20px;}
.black{background:#222;height:30px;}
.wrap:after{content: "\226A"; position:absolute; color:#c93838; border-radius:2px;width:40px; height:40px ; background: black; font-size:30px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; transform: rotate( 90deg); top:16px ; right:10px ; left:35px ; box-shadow: 0px 1px 14px 0px #000;text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #d95555;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
<div class="gray"></div>
<div class="black"></div>
</div>
```